# How to use NavigationView and NavigationLink in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Piece of code that I made for this question that runs in Playground:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Player {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
}

struct DetailView2: View {
    var player: Player
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(player.name) \(player.surname)")
    }
}

struct PlaygroundView: View {
    // MARK: - Propertiers
    @State private var selection = 0
    private var players = [
        Player(name: "Lionel", surname: "Messi"),
        Player(name: "Diogo", surname: "Jota"),
    ]
    
    // MARK: - View
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Settings").font(.title)
                    List(0..<players.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView2(player: players[index])) {
                            Text("\(index)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Players")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Players")
            }
            .tag(0)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Settings").font(.title)
                List(0..<2, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("#\(index)")
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "book.fill")
                Text("Foo")
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct Playground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlaygroundView()
    }
}
```

Current *Players* bar:
[image]

Current *Settings* bar:
[image]

How can I fix the code such that "Players" bar will look like *Settings* bar (it terms of the styling of the title). It seems like I've got the tab item and navigation working already.

Comment: You need to set a `navigationBarTitle`. I recommend you read up a little first: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Comment: @ClausJørgensen thanks for the link! Actually I don't wanna set `navigationBarTitle` since I wanna use a custom formatting for the title (e.g., center it to the top without leading alignment).

Comment: Use a `VStack` with a `Spacer()` below your content then (otherwise it'll be centred)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen could you please look again? I've mode some progress after I read the article and there's only one small issue left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking something like below (prepared & tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

[image: demo] [image: demo2]

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
         VStack {
            Text("Settings").font(.title)

            NavigationView {
                List(0..<players.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView2(player: players[index])) {
                        Text("\(index)")
                    }
                }
                     .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                     .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
            Text("Players")
        }
        .tag(0)
        
        VStack {
            Text("Settings").font(.title)
            List(0..<2, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("#\(index)")
            }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "book.fill")
            Text("Foo")
        }
        .tag(1)
    }
}
```